# dplyr: function error message

Tags: r, dplyr

I created a function to subtract some of my data based on an id. The function was working fine until `dplyr` updated. Initially the function wasn't accepting the column name as input in the function. I used [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) to adjust the function to accept the column name, however I am now getting a new error message.

```
testdf <- structure(list(date = c("2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", 
                        "2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-04"), sensorheight = c(1L, 
                                                                                    16L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 16L), farm = c("McDonald", "McDonald", 
                                                                                                                     "McDonald", "McDonald", "McDonald", "McDonald"
                                                                                    ), location = c("4", "4", "5", "5", "Outside", "Outside"), Temp = c(122.8875, 
                                                                                                                                                        117.225, 102.0375, 98.3625, 88.5125, 94.7)), .Names = c("date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                "sensorheight", "farm", "location", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           6L), class = "data.frame")


DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

  DailyInOutDiff04 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else !!variable[location=="4"] - !!variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "4")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  DailyInOutDiff05 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(5, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else !!variable[location=="5"] - !!variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "5")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  temp.list <- list(DailyInOutDiff04, DailyInOutDiff05)
  final.df = bind_rows(temp.list)
  return(final.df)
}

test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, quo(Temp))
```

I would like to know what the error message means and how to fix it.

```
 Error in location == "4" : 
    comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the precedence of `!` is causing problems.  When that happens it looks like `UQ` should be used in place of `!!`.

In that case, the first part of your function would look like

```
DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

    variable = enquo(variable)

    df %>%
        filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
        group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
        arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
        summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else UQ(variable)[location == "4"] - 
                    UQ(variable)[location == "Outside"], 
                location = "4")

}
```

This now runs without error.

```
DailyInOutDiff(testdf, Temp)

        date sensorheight     farm   Diff location
       <chr>        <int>    <chr>  <dbl>    <chr>
1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald 34.375        4
2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald 22.525        4
```

I think using `UQ` is probably the best way to do this.  Another alternative is to use the extract brackets in the form of a function.  This also bypasses the precedence problem.

For example, code that looks like

```
!!variable[location == "4"]
```

can be rewritten as

```
`[`(!!variable, location == "4")
```

Making these changes to the first part of your function, things would look like

```
DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

    variable = enquo(variable)

    df %>%
        filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
        group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
        arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
        summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else `[`(!!variable, location == "4") - 
                    `[`(!!variable, location == "Outside"), 
                location = "4")

}
```

Which also runs without error

```
DailyInOutDiff(testdf, Temp)

        date sensorheight     farm   Diff location
       <chr>        <int>    <chr>  <dbl>    <chr>
1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald 34.375        4
2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald 22.525        4
```

Comment: `UQ` works great and I like the inclusion of `enquo` in the function. Thanks.